# How to solve "Address already in use" when restarting a client-server application?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, process

I have a client-server application written in C. A hardcoded port number is used for socket communication between the client and the server. After every run of the application, I have to wait for some time before restarting it again given that the socket enters the `TIME_WAIT` state after the server exists. If I don't wait, the new run of the server errors out with "Address already in use". My code is based on [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Here is the sequence of calls made on the server side:

```
sock = socket(...);
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &OK, sizeof(int)); //OK=1
bind(sock, ...);
listen(sock, BACKLOG);
while(someCondition) {
    select(sock+1, &readFDs, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    newSock = accept(sock, ...);
    recv(newSock,...);
    send(newSock,...); // ACK
    close(newSock);
}
close(sock);
return 0;
```

On the client side, a connection is established to send a request to the server and then closed as soon as a response is received from the server. The sequence of calls is as follows:

```
clientSock = socket(...);
connect(clientSock, ...);
send(clientSock, ...);
recv(clientSock, ...);
close(clientSock);
```

Is there a way to be able to restart the server immediately without having to wait?
Can I avoid that the socket created by the server enters the `TIME_WAIT` state?
Is there a way to pick a different port for every run?

Comment: use SO_REUSEPORT instead - see [How do SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/how-do-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-differ).

Comment: You should make this an answer, @SteffenUllrich ?

Comment: Unfortunately, my Linux version is < 3.9. According to the link you suggested, SO_REUSEPORTis not available.